# The problems be Cannot read property 'key' of undefined in react native?

Tags: react-native, jsx

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24nV9.png)

I'm getting the problem since yesterday, I didn't find any solution for it, please help me,
Although I don't have a typo in the codeز

**App.js**

```js
import React from "react";
import LogIn from "./components/LogIn";
import Sales from "./components/Sales";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          options={{
            headerTintColor: "#0b4079",
            headerShown: false,
            cardStyle: {
              backgroundColor: "#fff"
            }
          }}
          name="تسجيل الدخول"
          component={LogIn}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          options={{
            headerShown: false
          }}
          name="المبيعات"
          component={Sales}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you include the code that's actually throwing the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the image you attached, it seems the issue is in `StackView.tsx`, not `App.js` which is directly related to [react-navigation](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation) in their source [here](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/67f6950c14b5ec1baa4359162c3c59b1b2fec94d/packages/stack/src/views/Stack/StackView.tsx#L289).

Can you provide more code snippets where the error is being thrown―further down the stack trace? The `App.js` isn't the problem here, because running that on its own seems to work fine on my end.

Comment: Thanks, I found the error. It was in the Stack version in package.json .

Comment: which version did you use?